# Adding files to Visual Studio installer project in a relative manner

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, installation

I'm trying to build a new installer project using Visual Studio 2010. The problem is that the installation files should be taken relatively to project's location, so I guess I need to specify a relative path, e.g: `"..\..\..\some_folder\veryImportant.dll"`

The problem is that the installer project is providing me only with a `.vdproj` file which doesn't contain location/paths to any of the manually added files (when I do right click on the project and add new files).

Just to make sure my question is clear enough:

Let say my project sits under `D:\develop\backend\MainProject\Project\Installer`, I would like to import some DLLs from `D:\develop\backend\MainProject\SDKDLLs` adding them manually by specifying their absolute location isn't good for me

> (d:\develop\backend\MainProject\SDKDLLs\core.dll)

Thanks for your help.

**Edit:** After reviewing the project file a bit deeper, I realized the paths are already relative:

```
       "{1FB2D0AE-D3B9-43D4-B9DD-F88EC61E35DE}:_1E8A546C985F494593B28567414EE00D"
        {
        "SourcePath" = "8:..\\..\\a\\b\\c\\d\\e\\f.dll"
        "TargetName" = "8:f.dll"
        "Tag" = "8:"
        "Folder" = "8:_34476923AC9546E4B47A8B966C915E0B"
        "Condition" = "8:"
        "Transitive" = "11:FALSE"
        "Vital" = "11:TRUE"
        "ReadOnly" = "11:FALSE"
        "Hidden" = "11:FALSE"
        "System" = "11:FALSE"
        "Permanent" = "11:FALSE"
        "SharedLegacy" = "11:FALSE"
        "PackageAs" = "3:1"
        "Register" = "3:1"
        "Exclude" = "11:FALSE"
        "IsDependency" = "11:FALSE"
        "IsolateTo" = "8:"
        }
```

It seems like the wizard already does it automatically. Is there a way to specify the relative-location manually and not by editing the **.vdproj** file?

Comment: Could you show the content of vsproj file? I think that you can solve your problem with HintPath

Comment: @outcoldman: it's a project among many others, so the vsproj is quite big, you still want me to past it here?

edit: i posted a piece of the vdproj file

Comment: @igalk, are you asking about adding files to the `.vdproj` programmatically?

Comment: @SimonMcKenzie: no, when i choose to add new files through the "right click-> add new files" i specify an absolute path, for example: "c:\a\b\c\d.dll".
my question is more about if it was possible to insert through the "file browser object" something like this "..\..\..\d.dll" when the base directory is from my release/debug directory.

Comment: @igalk, in my Visual Studio, the "Add Existing File" option always pops up in the project folder, 2 levels above the `\bin\Debug` folder, and I can certainly write "..\..\etc.dll", so can't you do the same thing but exclude two levels of `..` references?

Comment: @SimonMcKenzie: just realized that my original edit, actually answered my own question.

the VS already stores the paths relative and appereantly saves the absolute path in a global variable or so, according to the vdproj, represented as '8:' which probably means path to the debug/release directory

Answer (score 0):

The project is already initialized with relative paths.
so infact, no changes should be done by me.